# Gtest in VSCode, C/C++ intellisense shows errors

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, intellisense, googletest

I have an issue, which I guess is caused by the Microsoft C/C++ plugin. Intellisense is showing errors at Google Test functions, but there are no actual errors (tests compile and run without any problem).

When I hover over the functions with these red error squiggles, it expands to the functionality, F12 (go to definition) works as well.

How do I get rid of these intellisense "errors"?

I have tried searching for the error messages, for "intellisense Gtest VSCode" and similar, but no luck in finding any useful solution. My guess is that I missed something, but what?

Have also tried playing around with c_cpp_properties.json (tried to include the exact path to gtest, to force include the actual gtest.h file, etc) but no luck there either.

#### c_cpp_properties.json

It is pretty simple, basically:

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
],
```

#### somefile.h

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short a;
} myStruct;
```

#### somefile.c

```
myStruct s[5];

unsigned short someFunction(void)
{
    // Do stuff
    return s[somePosition].a;
}
```

#### test.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

extern "C" {
    #include "somefile.h"
    extern myStruct s[];
}

TEST(someTest, firstTest)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(s[somePosition].a, someFunction());
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(someFunction, secondTest,
    testing::Values(
        some_test{ "hello", 0 },
        some_test{ "bye", 1 }
));
```

#### VSCode C/C++ intellisense output

firstTest, error at EXPECT_EQ:

```
expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)C/C++(711)
```

secondTest, error at INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P:

```
namespace "std" has no member "string"C/C++(135)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by editing **c_cpp_properties.json**:

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "${workspaceFolder}/Tests/packages/Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1/build/native/include/**"
],
```